# Any nice place to communicate with c++/game developers?

Tags: c++, communication

I'm a game programmer working in Korea.
I started Stackoverflow recently and I found it helps me a lot.
Also I think communicating with other developers is a good way to learning and improving myself.
Stackoverflow is the only site I know to communicate (especially in English).

Any other nice place to communicate(ask/answer/talk) with game developers(or C++ programmers, network programmers)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net) has a great community of game developers, along with tons of great articles and resources related to game programming.

Comment: Gosh, I know that site but I couldn't think of that place have a community. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[Beyond3D.com](http://www.beyond3d.com/) is another good site (and [forum](http://forum.beyond3d.com/)) frequented by game developers and gaming enthusiasts.

Answer (score 2):

Too often people discredit IRC for it's abundance of high egos, and not to mention the ongoing war waged on infidels that promote spam terrorism.  Despite those set backs, it can often be a good source of information.  Typically if I go in there with an eagerness to learn and an openness to advice, I can typically find someone who is sitting at home bored and willing spend time teaching someone about something they have a passion for.

I would suggest logging into irc.freenode.net and looking for a gaming related channel.  If you have trouble finding one (it's a rather long list), jump on the C++ channel and ask anyone if they know of a good channel targeted specifically for C++ game development.

Be warned though...  sometimes certain channels can be rather clickish.  If someone is rude to you, don't take it personal.

Comment: Exact answer i wanted to tell. IRC after 20 years really rocks.

Comment: Yep, but unfortunately my thought out post didn't get the answer vote.  Instead it goes to the first guy to google "game development forum": http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=game+development+forum&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=